# Initializing inherited structs in Bond

Tags: c#, inheritance, initialization, bond

I have a Bond schema that (ideally speaking) would have some inherited fields:

```
struct Context
{
    10: required string thing;
    20: required string otherthing;
};

struct SampleEvent : Context
{
    20: required wstring evt;
};
```

and when I create my derived object (`SampleEvent`) I can do so like this:

```
        SampleEvent evt = new SampleEvent { evt = str };
```

but where can I set up initialization of the `Context` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base's fields are inherited and can be set in the same way as the derived's fields:

```
var evt = new SampleEvent {
    evt = str,
    thing = "thing1",
    otherthing = "thing2"
};
```

If you want to do this in a centralized place, I'd write a helper method. The generated code is partial, so you can use that functionality to add methods to the generated classes. You could also use extension methods, or a plain-old helper static method that's a factory for instances.